# Writing %post section in spec file ,but %post section isn't running

Tags: rpmbuild

I'd written a %post section in my spec file.
when looking in rpmbuild output, i can't see this post section, it's like it doesnt exist. Moreover, i can see other sections like %build, %install and %clean.
Can anyone guess way? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you attach the spec?

Answer (score 1):

The %post scriptlet is run after the RPM is installed, not when it is built, so it is normal for it not to appear in 'rpmbuild' output.  The %build, %install, and %clean scriptlets are run when the RPM is built, and that is why they are seen in 'rpmbuild' output.

Comment: great, so how can i test the code that i wrote in the post/upre/pre sections ? maybe by running rpm -i on the something.rpm file ?

Comment: Yes, you need to test install and remove on a target box. If you turn up the verbosity, e.g. "`rpm -Uvvh`", you will see all the commands being executed.

Comment: thanks! one more issue: i'm trying to define a variable in %pre section and use it %post section. but it seems that this variable doesnt past to the %post section:
%pre
if [ -e /etc/init.d/dan ]; then
     %define _installed_dan yes
else
    %define _installed_dan no
fi

%post
  if [ %_installed_dan == "no" ]; then
            do something...
  else
        do something else...
    fi